WSL2 cannot communicate with Windows gateway
Running WSL2 on Windows11.
Recently WSL2 looses communication to Windows firewall.
This is not a DNS issues on the WSL system.
WSL uses 172.22.32.1 as its DNS server and gateway.
This address is running on my Windows host as this
Ethernet adapter vEthernet (WSL (Hyper-V firewall)):

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Hyper-V Virtual Ethernet Adapter
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-15-5D-9F-2F-98
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::a58e:11df:17e:1a9c%62(Preferred)
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 172.22.32.1(Preferred)
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.240.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . :
   DHCPv6 IAID . . . . . . . . . . . : 1040192861
   DHCPv6 Client DUID. . . . . . . . : 00-01-00-01-2B-96-F2-45-F0-B6-1E-8B-5B-2D
   NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Enabled

I tried running this command and got this output:
> Get-NetFirewallHyperVVMCreator


VMCreatorId  : {40E0AC32-46A5-438A-A0B2-2B479E8F2E90}
FriendlyName : WSL


> Get-NetFirewallHyperVVMSetting -PolicyStore ActiveStore -Name '{40E0AC32-46A5-438A-A0B2-2B479E8F2E90}'


Name                  : {40E0AC32-46A5-438A-A0B2-2B479E8F2E90}
Enabled               : False
DefaultInboundAction  : Block
DefaultOutboundAction : Allow
LoopbackEnabled       : True
AllowHostPolicyMerge  : True


I assume the problem is the firewall is not enabled.
I tried enabling this with this:
> Set-NetFirewallHyperVVMSetting -Name '{40E0AC32-46A5-438A-A0B2-2B479E8F2E90}' -Enabled True

But it changed nothing.
Is this expected? Is the problem with WSL communication have to do with this firewall not being enabled? If so, why cant I enable it?

The default DefaultInboundAction is to Block the traffic you should probably change that to Allow. After you Enabled it, does it show as Enabled or Disabled? As there are multiple current versions of both Windows and WSL providing specific versions you are using or have installed is very helpful. Are you sure WSL is using 172.22.32.1 as the DNS server as that’s address to your Windows host.

Troubleshooting more, I found that disabling "Windows Sub System for Linux" in programs and features. Restarting. enabling it, Restarting, resolved the issue. However, I did the same process yesterday, and the problem came back today, and had to do it again. Note after doing this I checked the same settings of the NetFirewallHyperVVMSettings, and they look exactly the same as above, so not sure what is causing this. But it does not seem to be related to the settings I shared.
